# In Python, is it possible to make a while loop that will occur if an input is equal to different values?

Tags: python, while-loop

In Python, I am writing a program that allows the user to encrypt messages that they input. There are two methods of encryption that they can select, and I am trying to create a while loop that will trigger if the user chooses an option that is not equal to the two options, 1 and 2.

```
option1 = input('Which encryption method would you like to use? 1 = Across (NOPQ ...) and 2 = Backwards (ZYXW ...)')
while option1 != [1, 2]:
    print 'Please type 1 or 2.'
    option1 = input()
```

If I write this, than I will be asked to input `1` or `2` no matter what I type.

Comment: use `not in` instead of `!=`. Remember, you want to test if `option1` _**is in_** `[1, 2]` not if `option1` **_is_** `[1, 2]`.

Comment: and convert input to integer as well. Well in python 2 that'll work, but will break in python 3.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Or just make `1` and `2` strings. Either way would work.

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `!=` with `not in` like in the example below:

```
option1 = int(input('Which encryption method would you like to use? 1 = Across (NOPQ ...) and 2 = Backwards (ZYXW ...)'))
while option1 not in [1, 2]:
    print 'Please type 1 or 2.'
    option1 = int(input())
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to :

```
option1 = int(raw_input())
```

then as you want to see if it's in a list

```
while option1 not in [1,2]:
    print 'Please type 1 or 2.'
```

`       option1 = int(input())